# TYPO3 FLUID - image and for each - INLINE

Tags: image, typo3, fluid

i need this FLUID Code "inline":

```
<f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'textImageTeaserImage', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
<f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" treatIdAsReference="1" title="{field.textImageTeaserHeadline}" alt="{field.textImageTeaserHeadline}" class="img-responsive" width="1920c" height="780c" />
</f:for>
```

and here a Test with Image-Url:

```
{f:for(each: '{dce:fal(field: \'textImageTeaserImage\', contentObject:contentObject)}', as:'fileReference', iteration:'iterator') -> f:uri.image(src: 'fileReference.uid', treatIdAsReference: '1')}
```

but, it dont work :(

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: The `f:uri.image` ViewHelper does not seem to support inline rendering. The notation `{X -> <ViewHelperName>()}` means, that the "main" argument of the view helper (whichever one that may be) is set to `X`, nothing more (e.g. for `f:count()` the main argument is `subject`). All other arguments still have to be passed within the parenthesis. From the [source code](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/fluid_2_classes_2_view_helpers_2_uri_2_image_view_helper_8php_source.html) it seems like the image ViewHelper does not have a main argument, so it can't be used that way.

Answer (score 1):

Inline syntax reverse the order (child node comes before parent node). Correct syntax:

```
{f:uri.image(src: 'fileReference.uid', treatIdAsReference: '1') 
    -> f:for(each: '{dce:fal(field: \'textImageTeaserImage\', contentObject: contentObject)}', as: 'fileReference', iteration: 'iterator')}
```

Same can be used to render a section for example, in case you need to add additional markup that is not added by the ViewHelpers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use an own section for it in combination with the `<f:spaceless />` ViewHelper.

An (untested) example:

```
<f:section name="main">
    <f:render section="imgs" arguments="{field:field,fieldName:'textImageTeaserImage',contentObject:contentObject}" />
</f:section>

<f:section name="imgs">
    <f:spaceless>
        <f:for each="{dce:fal(field:fieldName, contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
            <f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" treatIdAsReference="1" title="{field.textImageTeaserHeadline}" alt="{field.textImageTeaserHeadline}" class="img-responsive" width="1920c" height="780c" />
        </f:for>
    </f:spaceless>
</f:section>
```

Comment: It's probably easier to use the `image` argument of the `f:uri.image` ViewHelper, instead of `src` and `treatIdAsReference`. No need to know whether the given thing is an image or an image reference.

Answer (score 0):

that work:

```
<f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'textImageTeaserImage', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
        <div style="background-image: url('{f:uri.image(src: '{fileReference.uid}', treatIdAsReference: 1, absolute: 1)}');">
        </f:for>
```

but this is not fine :)